# how to prefix identity column character in msSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I alter a table's primary identity column to include a letter before the number?  I have a table named `vendor_master` with a primary key `VendorID` that I would like to store as `v1`,`v2`,`v3` and so on

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vendor_master](
[vendorID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Vname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Mobile] [bigint] NULL,
[Landline] [bigint] NULL,
[Address] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[Pincode] [int] NOT NULL)
```

Comment: You can't do that with an auto-increment identity.  You'd have to use a separate table with an auto-increment ID and pull the "next" ID from that, prepending with a 'V'.  It will be a lot of work for that requirement.

Comment: it is not explicitly written into [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but identity is applicable only to numeric datatypes. and adding a letter you get a string...

Answer (score 1):

If it's important to you to have the field in your table, try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vendor_master]
  (
    [vendorID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Vname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Mobile] [bigint] NULL,
    [Landline] [bigint] NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Pincode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VendorKey]  AS ('v' +CONVERT([varchar](10),[vendorID])) PERSISTED
  )
```

Of course, that will yield you some weird results when sorting, so you might consider padding the data with zeroes to make it a consistent length:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vendor_master]
  (
    [vendorID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Vname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Mobile] [bigint] NULL,
    [Landline] [bigint] NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Pincode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VendorKey]  AS ('v' +RIGHT('000000000' + CONVERT([varchar](10),[vendorID]),10)) PERSISTED
  )
```

Comment: I think this is a bad suggestion.  You are appending a constant.  If it is always going to be the same then it is not needed at all.  Just concatenate in any select statement.

Comment: Hence the "if it's important to you" - given that the OP didn't explain the reasoning, I don't know how/why they want this. I'd agree that a SELECT statement makes more sense under most circumstances I can imagine, but without knowing why they want it and what they plan to do with it I figured I might as well offer a solution that does what they asked for in addition to the already-posted solution that might do what they *should* have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually do what you are asking.  Anyway, there is no reason to add the same letter to the front of a fields value.  Instead add the letter in your SELECT statment:

```
SELECT CONCAT('v', vendorID) AS VendorIDWithPrefix, Vname, Email, Mobile
FROM vendor_master
```